# Start roblox script with RemoteEvent

Tags: lua, roblox

How i can do something like that and fix this (i learn script)

```
local Event = game.ReplicatedStorage.SoundPlayEventWirlord

Event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, NameId)
    local theplayer = plr
    print(NameId)
    if NameId == "one" then
        game.Workspace[theplayer].one:Play()
        if NameId == "two" then
            print("IT IS TWO ?!")
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: In this example, is the `.one` child object of each character's model a Script?

Comment: .one is a Sound in players

Comment: What is the Script that you're trying to start?

Comment: i just dont know how to put a variable, how to do ? in a script like this :
local theplayer = plr
game.Workspace[theplayer].one:Play()

Comment: Are you asking how to fire a RemoteEvent with arguments so that the code inside the `OnServerEvent` connection happens?

Comment: i mean to put my variable "theplayer" in the script to play the sound u see what i mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, your question seems to be how to properly find the player's character model in the workspace.

You can do this two ways. You can use the player's name to index into the Workspace :

```
game.Workspace[plr.Name].one:Play()
```

or, you can simply use the [Character property of the player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Character) :

```
plr.Character.one:Play()
```

You should be careful though, as the Character model isn't guaranteed to exist in the workspace. So you should put safety checks in place :

```
if plr.Character and plr.Character.Parent ~= nil then
    plr.Character.one:Play()
end
```